# Target user not specified error on tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

When I try to call some methods like `show_friendship` I got the error

```
raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Target user not specified.', u'code': 164}].
```

Here is the complete code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
status = api.show_friendship("A", "B")
```

while I can use some other methods like `get_user`.

- Tweepy version `3.6.0`
- python `2.7`

Comment: have you found a way to fix it? I got the same problem

Answer (score 2):

`api.show_friendship` method accepts the "source" and "target" by either user ID or screen name. Therefore, you should specify the search method.

If source and target were the screen_names, then

this works:

```
relation = api.show_friendship(source_screen_name = source,target_screen_name = target)
```

However, this does not work:

```
relation = api.show_friendship(source,target)
```

For more information here is a [link](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L461)